# PHP fix zero-width-space inside string variable

Tags: php, str-replace, zero-width-space

I have zipcodes being outputted, coming from user inputted values.  Looks like it is outputting zero-width-space `\u200b` sometimes at the beginning of the strings.

What is the best way to replace these from within php before echoing the variable?

Comment: holy jsfiddle code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "&#8203;" being injected into my HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478847/why-is-8203-being-injected-into-my-html)

Comment: Don't have time to investigate this further, but it looks like this post is closely related.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478847/why-is-8203-being-injected-into-my-html

Comment: @AbdulAhmad - lol, yes, it is quite a doozy... sorry about that, but it is difficult to break apart also.

Comment: @JackPattishall - I have seen that question all ready, the answer is not entirely clear.  Basically just says the browser interprets it as a zero-width-space and that does not really provide a clear answer as to what the root cause of the problem is.

Comment: @SolomonClosson see my answer,it sorts correctly now.

Comment: Looks like the html is being outputted with `\u200b`, but how to get this with php or js?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I take the HTML from JSFiddle, and then copy a row with the invalid character (zip code with 07439, for instance), I get the following: http://jsfiddle.net/rjkkv3wv/5/ - Note, NOTHING has been changed on my end. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Using the hex viewer in the original link, I can view the characters. Looks like you solved the problem though in your answer :)

Comment: I'm hoping that my answer should fix this issue.  Seems like it fixes it, not sure if there is a better way to do this, but this is working for now.

Comment: Edited question, sorry for all the trouble here guys.  Please let me know if there is a better way to replace these zero-width-space chars within php, other than my answer provided.  If there is, I will be glad to accept the other answer.  I'm not that skilled in doing this in php.

Comment: Can't you validate user input befor saving it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this function to trim unicode spaces - this should work in your case too.

```
function trimUnicode($str) {
    return preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',$str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, seems as though this was coming from the actual string being echo'd by PHP, so I did the following to the string:

```
$zipcode = trim(utf8_decode($zipcode), '?');
```

All seems fine now!

Answer (score 0):

these are the steps fixed my issue

1. create a new text file.
2. copy the source code to new text file.
3. save the new text file and rename to (your file name).php and test again.

then everything is fixed.

Comment: This is not answering the question. Zip codes are from user input, not a static text file.

Comment: You are right, Hope it helps others if they have the same problem as me， thank you!