# GitHub API - Comment on Gist returns 404

Tags: javascript, api, github, gist

After following the documentation on GitHub's API, I got stuck on submitting a comment for a gist, the following code always returns 404, and the same call made in Postman too.

My JavaScript code as follows:

```
const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': credentials.authorizationHeader,
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.github.v3.text+json'
        },
        body: { "body": JSON.stringify(comment) } 
    };

    fetch(`https://api.github.com/gists/${gistId}/comments/`, config)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                dispatch(getGistDetails(gistId, credentials));

                dispatch({ type: SUBMIT_COMMENT_SUCCESS });
            } else {
                ToastAndroid.show('An error ocurred, please try again.', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                console.log(res);
                dispatch({ type: SUBMIT_COMMENT_FAIL });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Credentials I'm getting via OAuth:

```
accessToken: "redacted"
authorizationHeader:"bearer redacted"
clientID:"redacted"
idToken:null
scopes:"gist"
type:"bearer"
```

I tried changing the `authorizationHeader` to `token <oauth_token`, but still no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 404 is a `Not Found` error code. Most likely the `url` you're using points to an non-existing `gist`

Comment: The `gist` exists. As per the API's documentation, more often than not a `404` indicates a `403`, but my credentials are (supposedly) correct.

Comment: For reference, this is the `gist` I'm trying to comment on: `https://gist.github.com/desktp/8e376d6cd8d671e14c735d051eff7140`

Comment: looks like you have some hidden UTF characters in the query above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overcomplicating, as getting a gist's details through the API also nets you a `comments_url` field with the correct url, so no need to splice strings, falling into the very strange issue mentioned by @Zilvinas below. Also, a minor adjustment in the body to

```
const body = { body: comment }

const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': credentials.authorizationHeader,
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.github.v3.text+json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
};
```

fixed the subsequent `Problems parsing JSON` error I got.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some non standard characters in your GIST ID that are not even visible and I can't even get your link to work ( or is it private? )

[image: Your query]

Comment: That's really strange, I copied and pasted directly from the address bar. Still, in my code, the gist `id` is coming from the API. I first request the gist details, which occurs without a problem, but then the comment fails. Let me try the address here again: `https://gist.github.com/desktp/8e376d6cd8d671e14c735d051eff7140`

Comment: Nope, same thing again

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478847/why-is-8203-being-injected-into-my-html might just be your problem

Comment: This pointed me to the direction I needed to fix the issue. I submitted an answer with the solution.