# Remove tag &#8203 in WP theme

Tags: vim, whitespace

Bonjour à tous,
In my Wordpress theme, I don't know why, there's a kind of tag appearing juste after the body tag, as I can see in Chrome debug tools :

[image: Chrome debug]

It make a kind of blank space on the top of my page.

I read many posts talking about Sublime Text, that I use. 
Saving as UTF-8, Opening the file with VIM to see hidden tags...
I see nothing :

[image]

And I don't know if the problem comes from my text editor (?)

I think this appeared after I used ["Sweep" plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sweep/) for cleaning revisions.

Does someone have any idea how I could solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: The Same issue had been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478847/why-is-8203-being-injected-into-my-html). This may help you.

Comment: I already saw this post and tryed everything... but the last one idea. And  now it works :) Thanks !