# Blank space above header (seems to be random content)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm building a Wordpress website from scratch (plugin + template) and made today my header/sidebar.
The problem is that i have a blank space at the top of the website and don't know where it comes from.
When i inspect it i have this.

[image]

And here is the blank :

[image]

Thanks all...

Comment: Put your header.php content here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "&#8203;" being injected into my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478847/why-is-8203-being-injected-into-my-html)

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure this is due to the wordpress admin bar, try logging off and getting back on your website local host page without being logged on to wordpress. This should be only visible on the admin side, if not once you're logged off, try pasting the source code, will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers. Nothing was left in the header.php (checked twice) and tried too to go on the website without being logged but it was not that. I fixed it by sticking by header to top :/

Thanks !